# Why do I need to pass an express server instance as a parameter to the http module in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm currently studying Node.JS, Express.JS and Socket.IO. The tutorials that I've seen so far use a complicated sequence of code in order to initialize each of those modules:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
```

Why is the variable "app" passed as a parameter to the variable "server" and server passed as a parameter to "io"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express (which is not part of node.js) is implemented as a request listener with which you can initiate the http server implementation provided by node.js.

Check the docs:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener